# How to get correct environment when launching cygwin script?

Tags: cygwin

When I have this small script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello!"
sleep 5
```

I can launch it from my Cygwin bash and it works (=prints **Hello!**, sleeps 5 seconds and exits).

However, when I launch it directly from my Windows Explorer, double clicking the script file, opening it with Cygwin's `bash.exe`, it doesn't find `sleep` (*line 3: sleep: command not found*), unless I write it `/usr/bin/sleep`.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to open the script file with anything else than `bash.exe`, or is there some magic command that loads the correct environment?

Comment: what happens when you run using the run of windows and typing `<path_of_your_cygwin_install\bin\bash your_script.sh`?

Comment: launch bash with `-l` option so that is loading the proper login enviroment.

Comment: @BANJOSA: If I type `<path_of_your_cygwin_install\bin\bash your_script.sh`, the same happens.

Comment: @matzeri: When I launch bash with `-l` option, the next problem arises, because it then switches working directory to my cywin-`/home` directory.